# Expand only the column which is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following layout of three columns and I'm using bootstrap. When I click on a column each column next to that one gets expanded too. For some reason I cant get the snippet code to show it here so I attached an image of what I'm getting. 
[image]

If possible I would like to change this behavior. I would like to click on one column and expand only that one and not the other columns. Any ideas on how I can implement that?

```js
$('li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $('.col-md-4').toggleClass('flex-last');
    return false;
  });
```

```css
ul.ul_submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu a i {
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.submenu a.open i {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #2 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #3 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this fiddle somehow what you're looing for?
https://jsfiddle.net/florentroques/y2f6mjdz/10/

Comment: The behavior you want would be on desktop screen?

Comment: Yes that is correct! Because when in smaller screens the columns(each main category) will stack up vertically, one under the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Florent Roques.. actually no I was looking for something completely different. For some reason I cant get the snippet code to show what I have exactly. But to explain, I have three columns of categories and when I click on a column each column next to that one gets expanded too. If possible I would like to change this behavior. I would like to click on one column and expand only that one and not the whole horizontal row. Any ideas on how I can implement that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say horizontal row and vertical row in the last message. So I corrected the last message and sent it again.

Comment: Could you try to get the snippet working to show the problem you're encountering first? We'll be able to see what needs to be changed better when we have the initial HTML and/or CSS.

Comment: @Richard, this is the initial html, css and jquery code that I'm using. Regarding the snippet...  I have no idea why its not showing the grid of three different `col-md-3` columns like the image I have attached.

Comment: @Theopap I see. It seems like your snippet is working as intended, you just needed to go to full page mode ;-) I think it's because the Bootstrap CSS is kicking in; thus, stacking the items vertically.

Comment: Nice @Richard... I added another line now in the snippet so you can se exactly my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) is built using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) (I recommend reading about it if you haven't). Your HTML structure is currently built such that each row is one integral part, wrapped by `div.row`; you are building a single-line row that consists of three columns. When one of the child (your `ul submenu`) inside this `div.row` expands, it doesn't actually expand the other children, it expands the containing div (`div.row`). Because the containing block expands, it pushes down the bottom `div.row` and there's really nothing we can do about this. It's just how it works.

So if you want the behaviour you specified in your question, you should consider this HTML structure: build three columns, each consisting of `n` rows. Here's a working example (run in full-page mode). *One side effect is the ordering of the vertical stacking (though I presume this isn't much of a problem).*

```js
$('li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $('.col-md-3').toggleClass('flex-last');
    return false;
  });
```

```css
ul.ul_submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu a i {
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.submenu a.open i {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #2 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #2 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #2 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #3 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #3 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories #3 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
          <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
              <ul class="ul_submenu">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                  <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Richard :))))

Comment: @Theopap Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing to specify the element you want to work with :

```
var elementOne = $(".yourClass")[0];
```

This will select the first element with that class and for the others you can change the index as per your requirement!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Divyansh Singh... So basically you're suggesting this: `let elementOne = $( 'li.submenu a[href="#"]')[0];
    $( elementOne).click(
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $(this).next().toggle();
            $('.col-md-3').toggleClass('flex-last');
            return false;

        });`

Comment: Yes, but a simpler and more straightforward approach would be to just change **$( 'li.submenu a[href="#"]')** to **$('.submenu')[0]**.

Comment: I'm doing the following and when I click on something it's not expanding now. Also no error is happeing in the console `let elementOne = $('.submenu')[0];
    $(elementOne).click(
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $(this).next().toggle();
            $('.col-md-3').toggleClass('flex-last');
            return false;
        });`

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure based on the code provided but I believe the error is in this line:

```
$('.col-md-3').toggleClass('flex-last');
```

This finds every element with class `col-md-3` and toggle the class `flex-last` for each found element. (the behaviour you describe)

You could change it as follows to only search for the parents of the clicked element:

```
$(this).parents('.col-md-3').toggleClass('flex-last');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @de hart... unfortunately I'm getting the same behavior, the other columns next to the one I click are expanding too. By the way, in the inspect I'm getting this `class="col-md-3"` for the specific column I click on.

Comment: The code in the example you post works as expected. You could post the code you are using.

Comment: This is the initial html, css and jquery code that I'm using. Regarding the snippet...  I have no idea why its not showing the grid of three different `col-md-3` columns like the image I have attached.

Comment: I got the snippet to work... you just needed to go to full page mode and you see my issue.